# how do I check a radio button after being redirected

Tags: javascript

How can I check a radio button after being redirected to a new web page ?

I've tried this script :

```
<script>
    function AffStatus(choix) {
        document.getElementById(choix).checked = true;
        document.location.href = "PAGELINK?tri="+ choix;
    }
</script>
```

With these radio buttons

```
Sort by : <input type="radio" name="choice" id="ddc" value="ddc"
                on="AffStatus('ddc')" checked />Activity
            <input type="radio" name="choice" id="di" value="di"
                onclick="AffStatus('di')" />Date  <input
                type="radio" name="choice" id="nm" value="nm"
                onclick="AffStatus('nm')" />NBM <input
                type="radio" name="choice" id="p" value="p" onclick="AffStatus('p')" />Pseudo
            (A-Z)
```

**PS:** I'm redirecting the user to the same displayed page.

**EDIT:** I'm programming with Java EE using Eclipse not PHP.

But it doesn't work for me. I think that I've wrote a wrong script that I can't a solution to fix it. Any help please ?

Comment: If you redirect to another page the radiobuttons does not exist anymore. You want it to check just before you redirect?

Comment: I'm redirecting the user to the same displayed page

Comment: Are you trying to read a boolean value from this link and pass it to your checked property or what ??? your question is not very clear

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need to have separate code to check the radio buttons with same names. It will be automatically uncheck other and check the new one.

I found a mistake that you have on="AffStatus('ddc')" instead of onclick="AffStatus('ddc')"

I wonder why you are not using Jquery,

**EDITED:**

since you want to select the radio after refresh and you dont use the backend code to get the URL param 'tri', this function will help you..

```
function AffStatus(choix) {
    document.getElementById(choix).checked = true;
    document.location.href = "PAGELINK?tri="+ choix;
}

window.onload=function(){
    var selected_radio = getURLParameter('tri');
    console.log(selected_radio)
    document.getElementById(selected_radio).checked = true;
}

function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}
```

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't work. I'm trying to check the selected radio button after "refreshing"(=redirecting) the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get `tri` value from your link

**Function :**

```
var RequestQuerystring;
(window.onpopstate = function () {
var match,
    pl = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
    search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
    decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
    query = window.location.search.substring(1);

RequestQuerystring = {};
while (match = search.exec(query))
    RequestQuerystring[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();
```

**Usage :**

```
var myTri = RequestQuerystring.tri // your tri from the link
```

then pass `myTri` to your `Checked`